# Confused about one Verilog command

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hardware

Can anyone help me understand what the command below does?

```
reg [ADDR_WIDTH:0] wr_ptr_reg = {ADDR_WIDTH+1{1'b0}}, wr_ptr_next;
```

I know `reg [ADDR_WIDTH:0] wr_ptr_reg = {ADDR_WIDTH+1{1'b0}}` means assign `(ADDR_WIDTH+1)` 0's to `wr_ptr_reg`, but what does the rest (the comma and `wr_ptr_next`) of the command do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verilog allows you to declare multiple signals in one statement, separated by commas.

Your line of code declares 2 signals named:

1. `wr_ptr_reg`
2. `wr_ptr_next`

Both signals are declared as the same type (`reg`) and have the same number of bits: `ADDR_WIDTH + 1`

Verilog also allows for initializing a signal to a value on the same line as it is declared.  All bits of the `wr_ptr_reg` signals are initialized to 0.  Since there is no assignment to `wr_ptr_next`, all bits are initialized the unknown value (`x`), which is the default value for `reg` types.

If you find the syntax confusing, you can always declare the signals with separate statements (which is a common practice):

```
reg [ADDR_WIDTH:0] wr_ptr_reg = {ADDR_WIDTH+1{1'b0}};
reg [ADDR_WIDTH:0] wr_ptr_next;
```